# How to target the first <tr> in <table#id>, but not the first <tr> in <td><table><td>

Tags: html, css

The first row of table "tabid" is selected as intended. However the first line of the second table is also selected, which I do not want.

```css
table#tabid tr:first-of-type {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table id="tabid">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Select me</td>
      <td>cell-112</td>
      <td>cell-113</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell-121</td>
      <td>cell-122</td>
      <td>cell-123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell-131</td>
      <td>Cell-132</td>
      <td>Cell-133</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>, but not me</td>
              <td>cell-141-1</td>
              <td>cell-141-1</td>
              <td>cell-141-1</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>cell-142</td>
      <td>cell-143</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use child selector `>`

```
table#tabid > tbody > tr:first-of-type {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

### Result

```css
table#tabid>tbody>tr:first-of-type {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table id="tabid">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Select me</td>
      <td>cell-112</td>
      <td>cell-113</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell-121</td>
      <td>cell-122</td>
      <td>cell-123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell-131</td>
      <td>Cell-132</td>
      <td>Cell-133</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>, but not me</td>
              <td>cell-141-1</td>
              <td>cell-141-1</td>
              <td>cell-141-1</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>cell-142</td>
      <td>cell-143</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator), `>` like:

```
table#tabid > tbody > tr:first-of-type {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```css
table#tabid > tbody > tr:first-of-type {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table id="tabid">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Select me</td>
      <td>cell-112</td>
      <td>cell-113</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell-121</td>
      <td>cell-122</td>
      <td>cell-123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell-131</td>
      <td>Cell-132</td>
      <td>Cell-133</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>, but not me</td>
              <td>cell-141-1</td>
              <td>cell-141-1</td>
              <td>cell-141-1</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>cell-142</td>
      <td>cell-143</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code is given to me, as is. So I can not insert the <tbody>, as suggested. I also do not understand why including <tbody> solves the problem

Comment: @user3604103 Pretty much every browser inserts the tbody on its own so you can still use this. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bg61kw4u/. And it's the use of `>` that makes this work, not tbody